# Querying multiple tables connected by ICollections

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am working on this project where we were given a database to connect with EF database first.

I am trying to retrieve the address for a given customer.

Here is the Customer class:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Customer
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        this.WishLists = new HashSet<WishList>();
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public ICollection<WishList> WishLists { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

And the Address class:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Address
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Address()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        this.Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int AddressType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Suburb { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public AddressType AddressType1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

These two tables in the database are connected by a CustomerAddress table which EF has turned into public ICollection Customers { get; set; } and public ICollection Addresses { get; set; }.

My goal is to display a customer's address in my MVC web application. However, I am having a lot of trouble trying to write a LINQ query or equivalent to retrieve the address. So far I have tried:

```
// Return the details for current customer (this function works as expected)
public Customer CurrentCustomer(string UserName)
{
    Customer data = (from c in db.Customers
                     where c.UserName == UserName
                     select c).SingleOrDefault(); 

    return data;
}

// Return the address details for current customer (this function does not work)
public Address GetAddress(string UserName)
{
    // function to retrieve the CustomerID of the current customer
    var customerID = CurrentCustomer(UserName).CustomerID;

    Address data = db.Customers.Find(customerID).Addresses.FirstOrDefault();

    return address;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I am struggling to query two tables without a foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find the customer with `Username` first and then pass in to find its addresses. you can find it with a simple query.

To fetch just your customer's addresses change your method to this:

```
    public List<Address> GetAddresses(string UserName)
    {
        var addresses = db.Customers.Where(p=> p.UserName == UserName).SelectMany(a=> a.Addresses).ToList();

        return addresses;
    }
```

It returns a list of addresses based on customer UserName.

and you can use below method to return just one of the customer's addresses:

```
public Address GetAddress(string UserName)
{
    var address = db.Customers.Where(p=> p.UserName == UserName).Select(a=> a.Addresses.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();

    return address;
}
```

*I hope it's helpful.*

Comment: Thank you. I will try it when I get back in class on Monday.

Comment: do you want an address or all addresses of a customer from this method?

Comment: I've written both of them for you. You can develop it with lazy loading way but it has some performance issue. for you as a student both of ways is reasonable. good luck

Comment: so be aware if the customer has no address it would return null.

Answer (score 1):

You must use **virtual** in collections for EF to provide lazy loading for navigation property, by foreign key

```
[DataMember]
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

After that you can use query like this

```
public Address GetAddress(string UserName)
{
   Address data = db.Customers.Find(c => c.UserName == UserName)?.Addresses?.FirstOrDefault();

   return address;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.